# Reading content from positional text file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, fseek

I have text file having the following format

```
00151422    N8X 3V6 2013-11-11 00:19:00.000 IN          patricksoong@hotmail.com                    E       200-2462 Howard Avenue      Windsor ON  CAN N8X3V6  M   Dr. Patrick Soong

00331448    T6E 2R1 2010-03-01 00:00:00.000 IN          atirlea@yahoo.com                   E       9743 88 Ave NW      Edmonton    AB  CAN T6E2R1      Alina Tirlea Engstrom

00364578    K7N 1A3 2011-01-12 00:00:00.000 IN                              E       4463 Bath Rd        Amherstview ON  CAN K7N1A3  M   Mr. Martin Kandler
```

The above positional text file contains 3 records and 20 fields in each record. Also I now the size for each column. How will i read records and fields with in a record using PHP?

Size of fields are

f1=8;f2=10;f3=10;f4=10;f5=255;f6=50;f7=255;f8=10;f9=10;f10=50;f11=50;f12=1;f13=20;f14=50;f15=50;f16=60;f17=10;f18=20;f19=20;f20=1;

Comment: Why not just `explode` it and iterate?

Comment: We have no delimiter in the file.

Comment: The fields are not limited by tabs? It not, you should ask your provider to send you a CSV file, separated by comma or tabs... or something, else you need to parse it using `substr`

Comment: Let me try and inform you. :)

Comment: Also ÿþ character is added extra? Why this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `substr()` inside some kind of loop. Untested, but should give you an idea:

```
$lengths = [8,10,10]; // define all the lengths

function fixed_width_data_to_array($data, $lengths) {

    foreach($rows as $row) {

        $position = 0; // start at the beginning of the row

        foreach($lengths as $length) {

            // add current field to array
            $my_data[] = trim(substr($row, $position, $length)); 

            // move the 'pointer' to the start of the next field
            $position += $length; 
        }

        // add current row to an array
        $my_array[] = $my_data;

     }

     return $my_array;

}
```